# Is there a way to see what pending pull requests affect a particular file?

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch

There is a large open source project that I would like to make changes to.
With thousands of pull requests already pending,
its hard to know whether someone hasn't already made similar changes.

I can try to search for issues based on a keyword, but I'll likely overlook pull-requests that made changes to the file.

How can I search based on a filename, what pull requests make changes to the file?  There doesn't seem to be a way to do this from github.  Is there a git command I can run to print all pull-requests / branches that have modified a particular file?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182366/how-to-list-all-pull-request-with-count-of-files-changed/40185298#40185298) I posted to another question.  You could use pretty much exactly the same technique, but instead of counting the files changed in each PR, `grep` for a specific file instead.  Note the caveats at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

ElpieKay's answer is basically what I was suggesting in my comment; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182366/how-to-list-all-pull-request-with-count-of-files-changed/40185298#40185298) has an example shell script that would largely automated the process.

It turns out that it is fairly easy to get a list of open pull requests; you can just the following `curl` command line to get a JSON list of open requests:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/pulls
```

For example:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/centos-opstools/opstools-ansible/pulls
```

You can then extract the pull request numbers from that using something like `jq` (the `-s` argument to `curl` just suppresses some status output that you get when piping curl output to another command):

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/centos-opstools/opstools-ansible/pulls |
jq '.[]|.number'
```

You could then take the output of that command and pipe it into a loop to fetch just those pull requests and inspect them for a file of interest:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/centos-opstools/opstools-ansible/pulls |
jq '.[]|.number' |
while read pr; do
  git fetch --quiet origin refs/pull/$pr/head
  if git show --pretty=format:'' --name-only FETCH_HEAD | grep -q $file_i_care_about; then
    echo "PR $pr"
  fi
done
```

Which would yield output like:

```
PR 82
PR 71
PR 69
```

The above assumes that the variable `file_i_care_about` is a variable containing the file in which you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch all the branches in the pull-requests into the local repo and create a local branch for each of them.

```
git fetch <remote-in-Nth-pull-request> <branch-in-Nth-pull-request>:prN
```

If there are thousands, `N` could be from 0 to some thousands.

Suppose your main branch is `master` and all the other branches including forked branches are created directly or indirectly from some commits of `master`.

```
git log $(git merge-base master prN)..prN -- <foo/bar.c>
```

This command lists all the commits that change `foo/bar.c` after `branch-in-Nth-pull-request` was forked from `master`. If the output is not empty, we can conclude `prN` has changed `foo/bar.c`.

Run this command in a loop for every `prN` and you could get all the branches that have changed `foo/bar.c`

I guess there may be some easier methods to do the job, but you could have a try of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little script I cobbled together to solve a similar issue:

```bash
#grab all the PRs and sort them so the newest ones are first in the list:
git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head' | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | sort -n | tail -r |
#read each PR and filter for any that have changed file in question 
while read pr; do
  echo "Searching $pr"
  if gh pr view $pr --json files --jq '.files.[].path' | grep -q "yourFileNameHere"; then
    echo "Found in PR $pr - $(gh pr view $pr --json state --jq '.state')" 
  fi
done
```

(btw you'll need the github cli tool gh - https://cli.github.com/)