# How can we keep all pull requests and their respective commits locally in Github?

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have about 100 pull requests in a repository. The way I usually refer to some previous code is to go to the repo, find the PR and see the commits/files changed.

My question is: Is there a way to keep a track of all the pull requests Locally? I should have the same structure as my GitHub repo and should be able to go through various pull requests and search for files. That is, all those 100 pull requests should be there and I should be able to check them individually.

Comment: try it with following command: `git shortlog -n` (showed all **git pull** request from the respective branch).  Otherwise look at this question [how to list all pull request with count of files changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182366/how-to-list-all-pull-request-with-count-of-files-changed)

Comment: Have a look at [Github CLI](https://cli.github.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to pull all the pull requests individually to your branch.  GitHub has the refs `refs/pull/*/head`, so that `refs/pull/1/head` is the HEAD for pull request 1.  Note that issues and pull requests share numbering, so numbers may not be sequential.

This also only pulls down the branch, and not any of the metadata that goes along with it, such as reviews or comments.  You can access that the GitHub CLI or API if you want.

To pull those references, you'd adjust the appropriate remote section of your `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    # Add the line below.
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pull/*/head
```

Note that you almost certainly don't want to delete or replace the `ref/heads/*` line, but add an additional one instead.